# How I will get dropping media on mediaelement in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working with mediaelement in wpf, but the problem is I can't drop media on medaiaelement.
can anyone tell me the solution.the following code is .cs file code. I set allow drop property= true

```
  private void mediaElement1_Drop(object sender, System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {

        String[] FileName = (String[])e.Data.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.FileDrop, true);
        if (FileName.Length > 0)
        {
            String VideoPath = FileName[0].ToString();
            mediaElement1.Source = new Uri(VideoPath);
            mediaElement1.Play();
        }
        e.Handled = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tried it myself. Actually it will work after you play something there.
Here's the point: assume we have a Grid:

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True"></Grid>
```

It won't allow drop.
Now the following

```
<Grid Background="Transparent" AllowDrop="True"></Grid>
```

Will allow drop.

The first Grid doesn't have background at all, so actually there's no way to drop anything on it - there's no grid. And in second case there is grid's background even though we can't see it.

The same thing applies to MediaElement. Unfortunately it doesn't have any Background or Content property, so it won't allow drop until you start playing something there.

Solution is to handle drop on MediaElement parent container.

By the way, don't forget to set LoadedBehavior="Manual" for MediaElement so that it will play dropped file.

EDIT.

Here is explanation why MediaElement doesn't allow drop till any content was loaded in it.

Every WPF component is in fact composed of some other basic elements: Borders, Grids, ContentPresenters etc. So something inside the MediaElement handles drop. I cannot tell you what element it is because MediaElement's Template is not accessible. But it really doesn't matter what exactly is the element that handles drag and drop there. What does matter is that there's is nothing material in MediaElement's area until you load content on it - just like in case of my example with Grid at the beginning of this post. I mean that when you move mouse cursor over it's area there is nothing between cursor and MediaElement's container. Try to handle MouseDown event: result will be the same - it won't fire until you load any video. Why? Because there is nothing to raise event. Nothing cannot raise anything. 
As I mentioned before there is great difference between Background="{x:Null}" and Background="Transparent": in first case there's no background brush, no background, but in second case there is one. Feel the difference.

Comment: thanks for reply,still its not working,loading but not playing

Comment: Works for me. Replace your Drop handler's first line with String[] FileName = (String[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

Comment: k its working.but how it works at first time.can u tell me the process

Comment: What do you mean - how it works at first time? What process can I explain?

Comment: thanks man,when we drop on mediaelement at first time it didn't play.it working after we play something.how we play media when we drop on medaielement first time .can u explain that?

Comment: See my post after EDIT - I wrote explanation there.